# Azure AD to local AD / LDAP sync (for Radius)

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, azure-active-directory, radius

I am trying to setup a RADIUS server (mainly for 802.1X auth) that authenticates via Azure AD.  We currently have all our staff on Office 365.

I was thinking of using Azure AD Connect, however I believe that only syncs from local AD to Azure AD.

Has anyone done it or have any ideas on how I can get it done?  Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score -1):

We have used azure AD Connect and below is some check points what it basically does :

- AD Connect sync Local AD Identities to AzureAD Identities.
- AAD gives you functionalities like Password Sync,Federation
  Authentication,Password policy sync and many more.
- it is advanced and latest one than dirsync and AAD Sync tool.

below is the link where you can find comparison of all of them and you can come to conclusion which tool you should use which match your scenario :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-hybrid-identity-design-considerations-tools-comparison/

here is the link to get start with :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/